# Converting string of numbers and letters to int/float in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I feel like there has to be a quick solution to my problem, I hacked out a poorly implemented solution using multiple list comprehensions which is not ideal whatsoever. Maybe someone could help out here.

I have a set of values which are strings (e.g. 3.2B, 1.5M, 1.1T) where naturally the last character denotes million, billion, trillion. Within the set there are also NaN/'none' values which should remain untouched. I wish to convert these to floats or ints, so in the given example (3200000000, 1500000, 1100000000000)

TIA

Comment: what have you tried so far? can we see an example data set? This question is really poor and does not supply much info to help you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a function: and [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap) it to every entry in the dataframe:

```
powers = {'B': 10 ** 9, 'M': 10 ** 6, 'T': 10 ** 12}
# add some more to powers as necessary

def f(s):
    try:
        power = s[-1]
        return int(s[:-1]) * powers[power]
    except TypeError:
        return s

df.applymap(f)
```

Comment: Nice solution!  I think the only adjustment might be to change `return int()` to `return float()`.

Answer (score 3):

**Setup**
*Borrowing @MaxU's `pd.DataFrame`*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['123.456', '78M', '0.5B']})
```

**Solution**
Replace strings with scientific notation then use `astype(float)`

```
d = dict(M='E6', B='E9', T='E12')

df.replace(d, regex=True).astype(float)

            col
0  1.234560e+02
1  7.800000e+07
2  5.000000e+08
```

Comment: This is really smart !

Answer (score 2):

Demo:

```
In [58]: df
Out[58]:
       col
0  123.456
1      78M
2     0.5B

In [59]: d = {'B': 10**9, 'M': 10**6}

In [60]: df['new'] = \
    ...: df['col'].str.extract(r'(?P<val>[\d.]+)\s*?(?P<mult>\D*)', expand=True) \
    ...:   .replace('','1') \
    ...:   .replace(d, regex=True) \
    ...:   .astype(float) \
    ...:   .eval('val * mult')
    ...:

In [61]: df
Out[61]:
       col           new
0  123.456  1.234560e+02
1      78M  7.800000e+07
2     0.5B  5.000000e+08
```

Comment: Wow, what a coincidence. I just happened to see this page when you posted!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, yeah, i didn't expect it to be upvoted a few seconds after posting in such an old question :-)