# An easy way to turn a string with non integer characters, to an integer

Tags: python

Is there any easy way to turn string like

```
251.13M
201.41B
```

Into an integer?

Or is it the rigid approach(Only one I can think of) to find index of '.' and 'M' and do some substringing

Comment: Have you tried to write your own program to do it?

Comment: I'm in the progress. But it's becoming very tedious. Maybe because I'm not that skilled. So I were wondering if there was an easy way out there.

Comment: Do you want an integer or a float? I assume those are bytes? MB and B? Or millions and billions?

Comment: you could probably adapt this to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218728/converting-string-of-numbers-and-letters-to-int-float-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Can you give some examples of expected output. Presently its not clear whether the `M` and `B` have any bearing on the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that there is no direct way(i.e. a single function call) of getting the answer. But you could use a simple code like below.

```
valD = {"M" : 6, "B" : 9}

def getNumber(nstring):
    if nstring[-1] in valD:
        return int(float(nstring[:-1]) * 10**valD[nstring[-1]])
    else:
        return int(nstring)
```

Comment: That was alot smoother than what I was about to do, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to preserve the denominations you can use a dictionary to map the last letter to thousands, millions, billions, etc.

```
denominations = {
  'K': 1000,
  'M': 1000000,
  'B': 1000000000
}
```

You can then check check if that last character is a denomination, since it might be optional.

```
head = str1[:-1] # everything except the last character
tail = str1[-1]  # only the last character

# if the tail is one of the denominations, multiple the value
if tail in denominations:
    value = int(float(head)) * denominations[tail]
else:
    value = int(float(str1))
```

**NOTE:** This can be optimized further but I've written it out long hand to make it clear what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

If they are all of that exact format, this should work, as it lops off the letter at the end, casts it as a float and then an int, which should truncate the decimals.

```
int(float(str1[:-1]))
```

Comment: Or split on the period. Just cast the int